# Why am I able to upload custom object as a field to a firestore document?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

#### Firestore Data type confusion:

I am trying to upload a user document, but excluding the trivial fields, as a field of another Firestore document. Somewhat like a "mini user document" containing only their uid, username, name, and profile pic.

Why does Firestore documentation for "Add Data" state that custom objects are supported but within the "Supported data types," objects are not listed?

#### Issue at hand:

It says that custom objects are translated into supported data types, however when I follow the documentation I am getting an error when uploading my object:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __SwiftValue (found in field tempUserA)'`

```
public class ConsolidationDataService {
    
    static let instance = ConsolidationDataService()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func createNewBucket(bucket: Bucket, user: UserDictionary, collections: [String], handler: @escaping(_ completed: Bool)-> ()){
        let tempUserA = TempUser(
            uid: user.uid,
            username: user.username,
            profileImageURL: user.profileImageURL,
            fullname: user.fullname
        )
        let tempUserB = TempUser(
             uid: "",
             username: "",
             profileImageURL: "",
             fullname: ""
        )
        
        let bucketRef = db.collection("ConsolidatedBuckets").document()
        let consolidatedId = bucketRef.documentID
        let consolidatedBucket = [
            "consolidatedBucketId": consolidatedId,
            "bucketTitle": bucket.bucketTitle,
            "creatorUsername": user.username,
            "creatorUid": user.uid,
            "bucketLogCount": 1,
            "completedCount": 0,
            "uncompletedCount": 1,
            "bucketIds": [bucket.bucketId],
            "bucketImages": [],
            "collectionIds": [],
            "tempUserA": tempUserA,
            "tempUserB": tempUserB
        ] as [String : Any]
        bucketRef.setData(consolidatedBucket){ (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("There was an error creating a new document in the ConsolidatedCollection")
                handler(false)
            } else {
                print("Uploaded new bucket in the consolidated bucekts colleciton. Named: \(bucket.bucketTitle)")
                handler(true)
        }
    }
}

public struct TempUser: Codable {
    let uid: String?
    let username: String?
    let profileImageURL: String?
    let fullname: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case uid
        case username
        case profileImageURL
        case fullname
    }
}
```

I have also tried uploading the object with a dictionary in the struct defintion for the `TempUser` custom struct. It also does not allow the object to be converted to Firestore accepted data types.

```
public struct TempUser: Codable {
    let uid: String?
    let username: String?
    let profileImageURL: String?
    let fullname: String?
    
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        let data = (try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)) ?? Data()
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]) ?? [:]
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case uid
        case username
        case profileImageURL
        case fullname
    }
}
```

Function caller

```
ConsolidationDataService.instance.createNewBucket(bucket: uploadedBucket, user: self.user!, 
    collections: self.collectionsBeingAddedToArray) { (completed) in
        if completed {
            print("Finished.")
            self.showAlert()
        }
}
```

where `collectionsBeingAddedToArray` is of type `[String]` and `user` is of type `UserDictionary` which is a custom struct for the user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information to evaluate the second example.  In the first case, the `TempUser` struct instance must be converted to a `[String: Any]` dictionary.

```swift
    let encodedTempUserA: [String: Any]
    let encodedTempUserB: [String: Any]
    do {
        encodedTempUserA = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(tempUserA)
        encodedTempUserB = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(tempUserB)
    } catch {
        handleEncodingError(error)
        return
    }

    let consolidatedBucket = [
            "consolidatedBucketId": consolidatedId,
            "bucketTitle": bucket.bucketTitle,
            "creatorUsername": user.username,
            "creatorUid": user.uid,
            "bucketLogCount": 1,
            "completedCount": 0,
            "uncompletedCount": 1,
            "bucketIds": [bucket.bucketId],
            "bucketImages": [],
            "collectionIds": [],
            "tempUserA": encodedTempUserA,
            "tempUserB": encodedTempUserB
        ] as [String : Any]
```